# How to change the Product key for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We would like to change our product Key from trial. Please advise. We cant re-install the SharePoint as it is our production environment. Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Open your Central Admin site and click **Convert farm license type**

[image: Convert farm license type]

Enter your key and click OK

[image: Enter the key]

Wait

[image: SharePoint Wait screen]

Done

[image: license conversion success screen]

Screen shots from SharePoint 2013, but 2010 has the same functionality in the same place.